# adding slack web hook to rails app with slack-notifier gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the [Slack-Notifier](https://github.com/stevenosloan/slack-notifier) gem to add web hooks to my rails app.

I want a web hook to fire every time a new user is created in the database.

I have the following but I think my syntax is off. I get the following error in my IDE.

[image]

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Welcome to Pallet! Please check your email to activate your account."
      SLACK_NOTIFIER.ping("New Directory User: #{@user: @user.email, @user.discipline}", username: 'notifier', icon_emoji: ':confetti_ball:")
      redirect_to charges_path 
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

config/initializers/slack.rb

```
require 'slack-notifier'

    SLACK_NOTIFIER = Slack::Notifier.new( "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx", 
    channel: '#directory-bot',
    username: 'notifier'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All in all, this line looks problematic:

```
SLACK_NOTIFIER.ping("New Directory User: #{@user: @user.email, @user.discipline"}, username: 'notifier', icon_emoji: ':confetti_ball:")
```

I'm not sure what the intention of this line is, but there are syntax errors in this line. For instance,

1. The closing curly brace is supposed to be inside the double quotes for string interpolation.
2. Also, `@user` will translate into a ruby object. So I think you might gave meant `user:` instead of `@user:`.
3. Did you want an array when you wrote `@user.email, @user.discipline`? You'll need to explicitly put them in `[]`.

Not sure of the entire context, but I think there are additional issues with that line.

Comment: thanks. does this look better? `SLACK_NOTIFIER.ping("New Directory User: #{@user}, #{@user.email}, #{@user.discipline}", 
      username: 'notifier', icon_emoji: ':confetti_ball:')`

Answer (score 0):

If you open a string with a single quote, you have to close it with a single quote as well.

```
SLACK_NOTIFIER.ping("New Directory User: #{@user: @user.email, @user.discipline"}, username: 'notifier', icon_emoji: ':confetti_ball:')
                                                                                                               SINGLE QUOTE HERE TOO ^
```

If you open a `(`, you have to close it:

require 'slack-notifier'

```
SLACK_NOTIFIER = Slack::Notifier.new( "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxx", 
  channel: '#directory-bot',
  username: 'notifier'
)
```

There are more errors in the code that just those two, I am not going to point them out, because Stack Overflow is not a place for syntax validation.

You really, really need a crash course in Ruby to learn the basic syntax.

Comment: thanks those were just typos. i'm here now `SLACK_NOTIFIER.ping("New Directory User: #{@user}, #{@user.email}, #{@user.discipline}", 
      username: 'notifier', icon_emoji: ':confetti_ball:')`